# How to draw on QLabel with every QTimer emission

Tags: c++, qt

My goal is to draw on QLabel with every QTimer emission.
Here's how i'm trying to achieve this:

so, timer is created by triggering an action.
I want measures, parameters of which are updated as user inputs data to the dialog, to be drawn with every timer emission.

```
void ImageViewer::on_measuresAct_triggered()

    {
        dialog = new Measures;
        dialog->show();
        Ymax = Origin = Xmax = QPoint(30,30);
        measuresflag = true;
        pixtemp = imageLabel->pixmap();
        timer = new QTimer;
        connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(drawontimer()));
        timer->start(100);
        if(!dialog->isVisible())
            timer->stop();
    }
```

Here's the slot that is to draw the measures.

```
void ImageViewer::drawontimer()
{

    pixmap = pixtemp;
qDebug()<<"Hey there";
    pix = (*pixmap);

    QPainter paint(&pix);

    QPen MeasurePen (Qt::magenta);
    MeasurePen.setWidth(5);
    QBrush MeasureBrush (Qt::magenta,Qt::SolidPattern);
    paint.setPen(MeasurePen);
    paint.setBrush(MeasureBrush);


    paint.drawLine(Ymax,Origin);
    paint.drawLine(Origin, Xmax);



    QString originpoint = "(" + dialog->ui->olinex->text() + ", " + dialog->ui->oliney->text() + ")";
    QString xmaxpoint = "(" + dialog->ui->xline->text() + ", " + dialog->ui->oliney->text() + ")";
    QString ymaxpoint = "(" + dialog->ui->yline->text() + ", " + dialog->ui->olinex->text() + ")";

    paint.setPen(QPen(Qt::green));
    paint.setFont(QFont("Arial", 15, QFont::Bold));
          paint.drawText(Origin.x() + 8, Origin.y() + 18, originpoint);
          paint.drawText(Xmax.x() - 10, Xmax.y() - 8, xmaxpoint);
          paint.drawText(Ymax.x() + 8, Ymax.y() + 8, ymaxpoint);


    QPolygon poly1, poly2;

        poly1 << Xmax << QPoint(Xmax.x() - 12, Xmax.y() - 6)
             << QPoint(Xmax.x() - 12, Xmax.y() + 6)<< Xmax;

        poly2 << Ymax << QPoint(Ymax.x() + 6, Ymax.y() + 12) << QPoint(Ymax.x() - 6, Ymax.y() + 12) << Ymax;

        // style(), width(), brush(), capStyle() and joinStyle().
        QPen ArrowPen(Qt::magenta, 1);
        paint.setPen(ArrowPen);

        // Brush
        QBrush brush;
        brush.setColor(Qt::magenta);
        brush.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);

        // Fill polygon
        QPainterPath path1, path2;
        path1.addPolygon(poly1);
        path2.addPolygon(poly2);


        // Draw polygon
        paint.drawPolygon(poly1);
        paint.fillPath(path1, brush);
        paint.drawPolygon(poly2);
        paint.fillPath(path2, brush);

    imageLabel->setPixmap(pix);

}
```

But my program crashes. I figured out where my problem is by using "Hey there" message output with QDebug. It's in

```
pix = (*pixmap);
```

line of my code. If i comment this line program doesn't crash, nothing is drawn neither.
Declaration in .h file:

```
const QPixmap* pixmap;
        QPixmap pix;
        const QPixmap * pixtemp;
```

"Hey there" message is written 2 times most of the time, but 1 time out of 10 it's written 3 or 4 times. That confuses even more.
So, the problem is how i draw on a label (i suppose). Is there more convinient or "right" way to draw on label, which won't lead to crash of my program.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to draw into QLabel's pixmap or mangling with the pointers. Instead:

1. Create a new pixmap `p` on stack (local variable, no pointer) using the [copy constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#QPixmap-6)
2. **Check** if your pixmap is valid (`p.isNull()`)
3. Draw onto the pixmap `p`
4. Call `setPixmap(p)` on your label

A general note on Qt properties: Qt properties are not to be modified directly. The access to Qt properties always works through getting and setting. So, if you want to manipulate a property, you initialize a local variable with the getter, then modify your local variable, then use the setter.

A note about drawing into widgets: If you don't want to work on a copy, you can draw on a widget directly by deriving and implementing the `paint()` method. Furthermore, you can call `update()` on the widget to trigger a repaint (which will call your `paint()` method). This will be more efficient than using a label with a pixmap.

Comment: I applied your advices to my code. Now my program doesn't crash and works as intended. Thank you!